# sql row value depending on other row value

Tags: sql, oracle

My table looks like this:

```
Name  | Text           |    GroupID
------------------------------------
A     | sometext       |    1
B     | x              |    2
C     | x              |    3
D     | sometext2      |    1
E     | x              |    2
F     | abc            |    
G     | sometext3      |    1
H     | x              |    2
I     | x              |    3
```

GroupID 1 -> It's a header line and should not be selected
GroupID 2-... -> IT's a Subline from the above header (ID = 1) and should be selected  with the text of its header line! 
If there is no group id at all then the line should be selected with no text

So when selecting everything from the above table the result should be:

```
 B    sometext    2
 C    sometext    3
 E    sometext2   2
 F             
 H    sometext3   2
 I    sometext3   3
```

Does anyone have an idea how to build the select-stmt?

Comment: How to know Name `B` is subline of `A`?

Comment: There are other columns that have an order id which guarantee me the order you can see above

Comment: Ordering is okay, but there should be a column to link the set of data `A, B and C`.

Comment: No there ain't, I didn't create the table I just have to work with it so thats all I got

Comment: The order is determined with `ORDER BY Name`?

Comment: No the values in the name column can be anything (not in a specific order) just concentrate on the groupid "order"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query:

```
select 
 t1.name,
 case when t1.groupid is null then '' else 
 (select q.text from
   (select rownum as counter,name,text from TableName where groupid=1)q 
 where 
  q.counter = (select max(rownum) from TableName t2 where groupid=1 and
  t2.name<=t1.name))end as Text,
 t1.groupid 
from 
 TableName t1 
where 
 (t1.groupid<>1 or t1.groupid is null);
```

Comment: Why do you have the `t2.name <= t1.name`? The names can be anything in my table, so they are not ordered in any way...

Answer (score 1):

try also this ([live demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b77c/64)):

```
-- here I return the headers without subheaders - GroupId NULL
select name, 
       case 
          when GroupID is null then null 
          else text 
       end header
from t
where groupid is null
union all
-- here I return the the others
select sub.name, 
       head.text
from t head
inner join (
              -- here I take for each sub the associated header
              select t.name, max(h.name) header
              from t
              inner join (select t.Name, t.Text from t where groupid = 1) h
                      on h.name < t.name
              where groupid > 1
              group by t.name
            ) sub on head.name = sub.header
order by 1
```